# Return null value in ServiceStack json

Tags: c#, serialization, servicestack

In case when object is null, service stack returns

```
{}
```

But I want to return null value, how I can achieve this?

My serialization code:

```
    public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, System.Net.Http.HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => JsonSerializer.SerializeToStream(value, type, writeStream));
        return task;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

By adding the global configuration in your AppHost:

```
JsConfig.IncludeNullValues = true;
```

Comment: Above config is only for null properites, not for whole objects, in my case it will not help

Comment: @mkul right it can't serialize a null instance that doesn't exist